# Why do some fields not use arXiv?

Tags: publications, arxiv

My field is theoretical cosmology. I use [the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/) to find virtually every paper I read. Most preprints are updated with their peer-reviewed, published versions so I don't have concerns about their scientific legitimacy. However, when I've had to work on assignments or projects in other fields or subfields for courses at university I find myself constantly running into journal paywalls, which is very frustrating. For this reason I want to know why the arXiv's system of free access preprints is not more widely used.

In [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/16833/49043) it is stated that

> Compared with other fields, mathematics and physics are anomalous in making heavy use of the arXiv, with physics even more so than mathematics.

This tallies with my experience. The answer then goes on to say

> Things are trickier in other fields, because many of the advantages depend on network effects. If nobody in your field pays attention to a server, it's not conventional, and it counts for little or nothing regarding priority, then there's less reason to post to it (although it still has some value).

Is this the only reason that some fields don't post preprints on arXiv? Should we expect to see more fields publishing on arXiv in the future as the word gets around?

Comment: Interesting, not all fields from Physics use ArXiv as well.

Comment: Well, the arxiv has been around for a while now.  It would be interesting to know its growth rate, but I would guess it's much less now than 10-15 years ago.  The idea that posting a paper to a timestamped, open access, widely accessible internet forum doesn't establish its priority doesn't make any sense to me, by the way.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: here are some statistics on the number of papers submitted to the arXiv: https://arxiv.org/help/stats/2016_by_area/index . Looks like the growth is faster than linear, but only by a bit.

Comment: arXiv may be the largest repository of papers in some fields but it is also the largest repository of terrible papers, papers containing various misprints etc. in said fields.  *Caveat emptor*

Comment: Regarding the paywalls: Your university will most likely have subscriptions to most of the important journals. Try to find out how to access them. At some universities, it suffices to just visit the corresponding homepage from a university server (by being on campus or with VPN), at other universities you might need to go to the library. But you should be able to get your hands at most of the online published papers through your university.

Comment: @Bemte yes, I am aware of this, and my university does have some subscriptions.

Comment: Biology has the [bioRxiv](http://biorxiv.org/), though I suspect it sees less use than it could as authors are concerned about being scooped and/or they can't get the 10+ other co-authors to sign on to the preprint concept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several reasons why a field might not use arXiv, or another pre-print service. Whether or not these are *correct* is left as an exercise to the reader:

- It will interfere with publication. This is a little circular, but if a field doesn't use pre-prints, journals might not recognize a pre-print being put in a depository as *not* prior publication. Whatever merits there are in putting something in a pre-print repository are offset if you can't get it into a journal.
- Pre-prints create version sprawl. If there's significant revision of pre-prints, there's now sort of two versions hanging out, the one on the pre-print server and the one that sees publication.
- Priority is not necessarily as important (not that it isn't important). In biomedicine, the ideal is for multiple studies to all independently estimate an effect, so being first isn't as critical.
- Pre-prints are not peer reviewed, but a pre-print of an RCT or something may still be used to influence medical decision-making etc.
- Pre-prints and double-blind peer review are basically mutually exclusive. This one is, in my mind, the biggest downside of pre-prints.

When it comes down to it though, much of it is just field convention - if preprints aren't used, there's very little utility to being a "pioneer" in that regard - it's work, and explaining, and some risk for very little benefit.

Comment: Also: There are other preprint servers (more) specific for that field.

Comment: @skymningen Indeed. I was mostly touching on "Why not pre-prints at all?" which is a step before "Why not arXiv?"

Answer (score 3):

An important factor is how open are researchers in other fields to publish their manuscripts as a preprint. At least in biological sciences, we have biorxiv (inspired of course by arxiv) and several others preprint servers that are becoming popular. You can check some stats here: http://asapbio.org/preprint-info/biology-preprints-over-time.

This practice is also becoming extended to other fields. The Center for Open Science made available a platform for the creation of new preprint servers, e.g. https://osf.io/preprints/?_ga=2.149800182.1984918221.1511841280-890674891.1511841280

Answer (score 2):

It has not been mentioned, but the preferred document format for arxiv is LaTeX, and naturally, fields heavily relying on typesetting equations are more prone to use LaTeX.

I am not sure that word documents uploaded ca. 2000 are perfectly compatible with todays version of Office.

Comment: IIRC, you can upload PDFs to the Arxiv, as long as they haven’t been generated with LaTeX (in which case, you must upload the LaTeX source). Why would you upload Word documents?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: "*Why would you upload Word documents?* (raises hand) Oh, I know the answer to this one!! So the document can't be read in 10 years because of backwards compatibility issues. (sarcasm intended)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Making pdf from word documents is still magic for many...

Comment: I don't think this is a major barrier: there are lots of papers on bioRxiv that are clearly .pdfs created from Microsoft Office documents.