# Does posting a preprint to the arXiv reduce the chances to acceptance?

Tags: publications, peer-review, arxiv, online-publication, preprint

Depending on the submission journal, there may be some explicit rules allowing or forbidding the posting of a preprint before the peer review process is complete. However, for those journals that don't forbid it, is there any evidence that doing so impacts negatively on the prospects for acceptance?

Comment: The conversation about other benefits of arXiv has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109839/discussion-on-question-by-tfovid-does-posting-a-preprint-to-the-arxiv-reduce-the).

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the answer will depend on the field. In maths it is hard to find new papers that were not posted to arxiv first. Disregarding or even disallowing such papers would spell death for a journal. Thus, regarding acceptance there are no pros and cons, it will simply not matter. Regarding all the other aspects, such as visibility, etc., publishing a preprint is an obvious choice, but that topic has been discussed extensively [in previous questions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16832/why-upload-to-academic-preprint-sites-like-arxiv?rq=1).

I guess the same will hold true for physics and CS. It might be different in other fields where arxiv and similar sites are used less often, but it seems to me that there is a slow convergence towards extensive use of preprint repositories in all branches of science.

Comment: "It will simply not matter": not sure. When posting on arxiv is the norm, a paper that was not posted on arxiv looks suspicious. I would decline to review it if invited to do so by a journal.

Comment: This. It may have little impact in some fields, but for example for some medical journals, showing up in arxiv effectively sets the probability of acceptance to 0.